# What does gcc -lnsl this flag do?

Tags: gcc, rpc

Sorry for noobie question but I could not understand this .. what does gcc -lnsl flag do .
I tried searching over internet also read about rpc.

Answer (score 0):

This flag tells gcc to link the binary with `nsl` library. To be more clear, the line `gcc -lnsl` could be rewritten to more verbose equivalent `gcc -l nsl`. See [man gcc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html):

> ```
>    -llibrary
>    -l library
>        Search the library named library when linking.  (The second
>        alternative with the library as a separate argument is only for
>        POSIX compliance and is not recommended.)
>
>        The -l option is passed directly to the linker by GCC.  Refer to
>        your linker documentation for exact details.  The general
>        description below applies to the GNU linker.
>
>        The linker searches a standard list of directories for the
>        library.  The directories searched include several standard
>        system directories plus any that you specify with -L.
> ```